# Can't access my Firebase Realtime Database data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]I was developing an android app for a university project using firebase database. After returning to the app after I stopped coding on it for more than 2 weeks due to assignments and Exams, I realized my data isn't there just empty and I can't access the Rules i will get "Unable to load your rules". I realized after reading my emails send by firebase that i started developing my app in test mode and i will lose my data after 30 days (which i did). My Questions are how do i edit the rules to so i can access the data at any time ? and is there any chance i can keep on working on this project so i don't have to create another firebase project?

P.S.: The firebase authentication and storage is still there so i would like to regain access to the data to continue developing my app

Comment: *firebaser here* We've seen a number of reports from developers from certain regions having problems accessing the Realtime Database in the Firebase console. Please [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I already did

Comment: Most developers have been able to work around the problem by using a VPN.

Comment: using vpn solved the problem. Thank you @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 4):

*firebaser here*

We've seen a number of reports from developers from certain regions having problems accessing the Realtime Database in the Firebase console.

Since these reports seem highly specific to one region, there may be little Firebase can do about it. I recommend reaching out to your internet provider and asking them to ensure (web socket) traffic to `*.firebaseio.com` is allowed. In the meantime you might want to use a VPN to see if you can bypass the blockage.

If does not cover your case, or does not help you solve it, please [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

Your profile says that you're in Lebanon, where Firebase stopped working since Sunday when Ogero (the internet provider) blocked it on request by the government.